# Oracle SQL to calculate percentage

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to calculate the percentage based on the total students for each subject and by grade distribution.

I have table with the following fields:

- Student Id
- Term,
- Course
- final grade

[image: Sample Data]

I wrote the below query to get the total per course and per grade

```
select distinct  Count( StudentID ) as "Total",
       COURSE,FINAL_GRADE,subject,from table
 where term in('2000200')
       and subject in ('ENG111','ENG112,'ENG121',,,,,,,,,,,,etc)
       and FINAL_GRADE IN('A','B','C','F')
 group by 1
```

I cannot use the below code because it will calculate the overall total and not per subject  :

```
count(ID) * 100.0 / (select count(*) from Table) as 'Percentage'
```

the output should be similar to the below

[image: Output required]

please help

thank you

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: example: I have 18 student in ENG111 and I need to find out the % per Grade. 2 students with A , 5 with B , 10 with C and 1 with F  Percentage
(A = 11.11%), (B = 27.77%), (C = 55.55%), (F =5.55%). My problem is how to calculate the total per subject then use it calculate the percentage per Grade for each subject)

Comment: `group by 1` will simply put all the rows in a single group. In GROUP BY, the number 1 is treated as a hard-coded constant (which is the same for every row) - it is ***not*** a placeholder for "first column".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want aggregation with a window function to calculate the total for the subject:

```
select subject, grade, count(*) as total,
     100.0 * count(*) / sum(count(*)) over (partition by subject)
from t
group by subject, grade
```

[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6804b0/84/0)

Comment: Thanks a lot it works I did not know that there is a partition

Answer (score 1):

You can use the very nice oracle analytic function "RATIO_TO_REPORT" for that purpose like below.

```sql
SELECT subject, grade, COUNT(*) total,
       100 * RATIO_TO_REPORT(COUNT(*))over(PARTITION BY subject) Percentage
FROM T
GROUP BY subject, grade
ORDER BY subject, grade
;
```

Comment: Glad to see I could help